# How to perform Update operations in GridFS (using Java)?

Tags: java, mongodb, gridfs, mongodb-java

I am using `Mongo-Java-Driver 2.13` I stored a PDF file (*size 30mb*) in **GridFS**. I am able to perform insertion, deletion and find operation easily.

```
    MongoClient mongo = new MongoClient("localhost", 27017);
    DB db = mongo.getDB("testDB");
    File pdfFile = new File("/home/dev/abc.pdf");
    GridFS gfs = new GridFS(db,"books");     
    GridFSInputFile inputFile = gfs.createFile(pdfFile);
    inputFile.setId("101");
    inputFile.put("title", "abc");
    inputFile.put("author", "xyz");
    inputFile.save();
```

data is persisted in `books.files` and `books.chunks` collections. Now I want to **update** :

- case 1: pdf file
- case 2: title or author

> How to perform these Update operations for **Case 1** in GridFS ?

I came to know that I need to maintain multiple versions of my files and pick up the right version. Can anybody put some clarity on it?

**Edit**:

I can update metadata(title, author) easily.

```
    GridFSDBFile outputFile = gfs.findOne(new BasicDBObject("_id", 101));
    BasicDBObject updatedMetadata = new BasicDBObject();
    updatedMetadata.put("name", "PG");
    updatedMetadata.put("age", 22);

    outputFile.setMetaData(newMetadata);       
    outputFile.save();
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In GridFS you are not removing/deleting a single document but actually a bunch of documents (files are split into chunks and each chunk is a separate document). That means replacing a file is simply not possible in an atomic manner.

What you can do instead is:

1. insert a new file with a new name
2. after this happened (use the *replica acknowledged* write-concern), update all references to the old file to point to the new one
3. after you got a confirmation for this, you can delete the old file

GridFS is kind of a hackish feature. It is often better to just use a separate fileserver with a real filesystem to store the file content and only store the metadata in MongoDB.