# Is it possible to perform multiple DB operations in a single transaction in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, transactions, atomic

Suppose I have two collections `A` and `B`

I want to perform an operation

```
db.A.remove({_id:1});
db.B.insert({_id:"1","name":"dev"})
```

I know MongoDB maintains atomicity at the document level. Is it possible to perform the above set of operation in a single transaction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, now you can!

MongoDB has had atomic write operations on the level of a single document for a long time. But, MongoDB did not support such atomicity in the case of multi-document operations until `v4.0.0`. Multi-document operations are now atomic in nature thanks to the release of MongoDB Transactions.

But remember that **transactions** are only supported in replica sets using the WiredTiger storage engine, and not in standalone servers (but may support on standalone servers too in future!)

Here is a mongo `shell` example also provided in the official docs:

```
// Start a session.
session = db.getMongo().startSession( { readPreference: { mode: "primary" } } );

employeesCollection = session.getDatabase("hr").employees;
eventsCollection = session.getDatabase("reporting").events;

// Start a transaction
session.startTransaction( { readConcern: { level: "snapshot" }, writeConcern: { w: "majority" } } );

//As many operations as you want inside this transaction
try {
   employeesCollection.updateOne( { employee: 3 }, { $set: { status: "Inactive" } } );
   eventsCollection.insertOne( { employee: 3, status: { new: "Inactive", old: "Active" } } );
} catch (error) {
   // Abort transaction on error
   session.abortTransaction();
   throw error;
}

// Commit the transaction using write concern set at transaction start
session.commitTransaction();

session.endSession();
```

I recommend you reading [this](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.0/core/transactions/) and [this](https://medium.com/cashpositive/the-hitchhikers-guide-to-mongodb-transactions-with-mongoose-5bf8a6e22033) to better understand how to use!

Comment: Arpit it would be great for future readers, if you can add a simple shell example. Maybe copy from official docs itself.

Answer (score 2):

MongoDB can not guarantee atomicity when more than one document is involved.

Also, MongoDB does not offer any single operations which affect more than one collection.

When you want to do whatever you actually want to do in an atomic manner, you need to merge collections A and B into one collection. Remember that MongoDB is a schemaless database. You can store documents of different types in one collection and you can perform single atomic update operations which perform multiple changes to a document. That means that a single update can transform a document of type A into a document of type B.

To tell different types in the same collection apart, you could have a `type` field and add this to all of your queries, or you could use duck-typing and identify types by checking if a certain field `$exists`.

Comment: I am not able to merge collections. Actually I am doing it to achieve update in GridFS. As there is no way to directly update files in GridFS. So, I need to insert updated file and delete existing file. I want to do that part in a single transaction

Comment: @dev Why didn't you say so? That completely changes your question. In GridFS you are not removing/deleting a single document but actually a bunch of documents (files are split into chunks and each chunk is a separate document). Also with GridFS you operate on only one collection. But there are specific solutions for this scenario in GridFS. Please ask this as a new question.

Comment: I already asked a question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29515327/how-to-perform-update-operations-in-gridfs-using-java