# How to update Saved Document Extra data in GridFS

Tags: pymongo, gridfs

I have stored files on gridFS that has extra information stored on them - it is not set on the metadata otherwise I would use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29515327/how-to-perform-update-operations-in-gridfs-using-java)

For Pymongo 3.2.2 we stored information on the same level as the actual data in fs.files (not using the metadata)

so for example we have:

```
fs.files = [ {
_id, description, title, ...
}]
```

When I call GridFS.put like so and nothing happens

```
FS = GridFS(mongo_,)
file.description = request_data.get('description', None)
FS.put(file)
```

How can I update that file extra information such as description?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Manually update those extra fields without using GridFS:

```
file = mongo_.fs.files.find_one({'_id': ObjectId(fileId)})
file['description'] = request_data.get('description', None)
mongo_.fs.files.save(file)
```

Answer (score -1):

What is `file` in your code example? That is, what are you passing to GridFS.put?

To add metadata to a GridFS file, pass additional keyword arguments to `put`, [as it shows in the PyMongo tutorial](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/examples/gridfs.html#saving-and-retrieving-data):

```
>>> fs.put(b'data', filename='foo', description='my description')
ObjectId('5825ea8ea08bff9df5059099')
```

Now the metadata is stored along with your data in GridFS:

```
>>> gridout = fs.get(ObjectId('5825ea8ea08bff9df5059099'))
>>> gridout.description
u'my description'
```

Under the hood, you can see that PyMongo stored the metadata in the `fs.files` collection in MongoDB:

```
>>> for doc in db.fs.files.find()
...     print(doc.get('description'))
...     
my description
```

But the better way to access GridFS data is with PyMongo's GridFS API, not by directly querying the collections.

Another way to store metadata is to create a GridIn, set a field, and call `close`:

```
>>> gridin = fs.new_file()
>>> gridin.filename = 'foo'
>>> gridin.description = 'my description'
>>> gridin.write(b'data')
>>> gridin.close()
```

This is a good option if you need to call `write` multiple times with chunks of data.

Comment: Yes. All of this is correct. The thing is once you wrote `gridin.description = 'my desc'` and then fs.put - this will accept it but will not change the description field - you can't update the grindin.description using the gridfs system